# Get TableViewController from TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom class for a table cell that is connected to a switch within the table cell (with an action) and I want to be able to to communicate to the TableViewController that the action happened as well as the path of the cell. The way that initially came to mind was if I could use some function in UITableViewCell to get the TableViewController of the table the cell is part of, as my custom class is (rather obviously) a subclass of UITableViewCell. Please tell me if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a reference to the containing view controller, I add a weak property on the cell subclass.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UITableViewController *viewController;
```

You can assign this value in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

**For accessing each cell in TableView**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as YourTableViewCell
        cell.mainTextLabel.text = self.venueService.mainCategoriesArray()[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
```

**For getting selected cell in TableView**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell;
    print(currentCell)
}
```

**Reaching from TableViewCell to TableView**

```
self.superview //// self is TableViewCell and its superview represents TableViewController
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should make the ViewController the target of the switch action.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SwitchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell
    cell.onSwitch.addTarget(self, action: Selector("cellSwitchDidChange:"), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    cell.label.text = "This is a Switch"
    return cell
}

func cellSwitchDidChange(sender: UISwitch) {
    let origin = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(origin)!
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This can cause multiple calls for a single switch because you keep on adding targets without removing them in `prepareForReuse`